# Why is this HTML form producing only 8 parameters instead of 9?

Tags: php, html

I want to send a number of parameters by the form to a php file to insert to the database,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Self</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    function selfcheck($DB, $TechID, $ClientID, $SiteID, $Type, $LogTime){
        $dbConnection = mysql_connect($DB['server'], $DB['loginName'], $DB['password']);
        if(!$dbConnection){
            die('Error! ' . mysql_error());
            }
        mysql_select_db($DB['database'], $dbConnection);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log") or die('Error! ' . mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $count = $row['COUNT(*)'];
            $count = $count+1;
            print $count.", ".$TechID.", ".$ClientID.", ".$SiteID.", ".$LogTime.", ".$Type."<br>";
            $query = "INSERT INTO Log (LogID, TechID, ClientID, SiteID, LogTime, Type)
                        VALUES (".$count.", ".$TechID.", ".$ClientID.", ".$SiteID.", ".$LogTime.", ".$Type.")";
            mysql_query($query);
        }
    }

    $LogTime = date('Y/m/d H:i', mktime($_GET['Hour'], $_GET['Minute'], 0, $_GET['Month'], $_GET['Day'], $_GET['Year']));
    selfcheck($DB, $_GET['TechID'], $_GET['ClientID'], $_GET['SiteID'], $_GET['Type'], $LogTime);
?>
</body>
```

As you can see, there are nine Get values, however, when I try to execute the codes, the server replys

```
"Undefined index: Minute in C:\wamp\www\NFC\self.php on line 29", and show in the URL, minute parameter has not been sent. Why does this happen? And how can I solve this problem?
```

Here is the code to send the request.

```
print "<form method='get' name='check' action='self.php'>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tech") or die('Error! '.mysql_error());
    print "Name<select id='tech' name='TechID'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print "<option value=".$row['TechID'].">".$row['TechName']."</option>";
    }
    print "</select>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Client") or die('Error! '.mysql_error());
    print "Name<select id='client' name='ClientID'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print "<option value=".$row['ClientID'].">".$row['ClientName']."</option>";
    }
    print "</select>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Site") or die('Error! '.mysql_error());
    print "Name<select id='site'name='SiteID'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print "<option value=".$row['SiteID'].">".$row['SiteName']."</option>";
    }
    print "</select>";
    print "Type<select id='type' name='Type'>";
    print "<option value='Checkin'>Check In</option>";
    print "<option value='Checkout'>Check Out</option>";
    print "</select><br>";
    print "Year<input type='text' id='year' size='4' name='Year'/>";
    print "Month<input type='text' id='month' size='2' name='Month'/>";
    print "Day<input type='text' id='day' size'2' name='Day'/>";
    print "Hour in 24<input type='text' id='hour' size='2' name='Hour'/>";
    print "Minute<input type='text' id='minute' size'2'name='Minute'/>";
    print "<input type='submit' value='Manual check' onclick='self.php'/>";
    print "</form>";
```

it is in a PHP file as for some choices, I want to get the options from the database instead of hard code them. I have tried to send the parameters through a javascript file, but the situation cannot be solved.

Comment: Give the result of `var_dump($_GET);` from self.php.

Comment: array (size=8)
  'TechID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'ClientID' => string '2' (length=1)
  'SiteID' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Type' => string 'Checkin' (length=7)
  'Year' => string '2012' (length=4)
  'Month' => string '07' (length=2)
  'Day' => string '16' (length=2)
  'Hour' => string '10' (length=2)
it gives out an array of 8 variables, so what can I do?

Comment: There is nothing like `Minute` in the array.

Comment: its becose of invalid html as Paul says, to help you write valid html you can use validation tools like [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really aren't helping yourself by constructing your markup in this way.

I suspect your answer is here:-

```
print "Minute<input type='text' id='minute' size'2'name='Minute'/>";
```

No space between the end of the **size** attribute and the beginning of the **name** attribute.  As far as the page that picks this value up is concerned, the value 'Minute' does not exist.

Change it to:-

```
print "Minute<input type='text' id='minute' size='2' name='Minute'/>";
```

Comment: +1 yes, that's the problem.  Nine variables isn't remotely near the limit for a `GET` request.

Comment: @PugganSe I fixed that for him.

Comment: its fixed for Pauls answer, but OP have a few more of them

Comment: @PugganSe ah yes, so he does.  At least those won't actually break the form :)

Answer (score -1):

For submitting form data you using the GET-Method. This method has a limit to submitting data. Using the POST-Method for it. There is quite unlimited space for submitting data.

PS: Try to avoid write Html with php, use the normal way instead.

Comment: ya, I know, I just want to see the output, that is why I form an html temporarily. Let me have a try first.

Comment: don't be distracted by the OP's supposition that this is somehow a GET limitation.  The real problem is just a syntax error in his HTML.

Comment: @Alniak: thanks for informing me. your eyes are sharpener than my ones. :-)

Comment: I would like to ask why when i change it to post method, Notice: Undefined index: Minute in C:\wamp\www\NFC\self.php on line 29 such message occur?

Comment: @user1502740 you don't need to change to `POST` - just fix your HTML.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP ini file you could find `max_input_time` & `post_max_size` both of these constants affects the POST or GET data. In case of GET the max URL length also applies.